# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to put `IF`..`ELSE` in `WHERE` clause as below but getting error message

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. Incorrect syntax near ')'."

```
DECLARE @categoryID int

SET @categoryID = 0

SELECT * from SE_Auctions
  WHERE ItemCategoryID IN
  (
   IF @categoryID = 0
     SELECT CategoryID from SE_ItemCategory
   ELSE
     SELECT CategoryID from SE_ItemCategory 
    WHERE ParentID = @categoryID 
          OR CategoryID = @categoryID
  )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use an `IF` inside a subselect in that manner.  Instead, use an `AND` to test for the value of the variable `@categoryID` in the `WHERE` clause.  This will require two `()` groups with a logical `OR` between them.

```
WHERE 
-- First case, @categoryID = 0
(@categoryID = 0 AND ItemCategoryID IN (
  SELECT CategoryID from SE_ItemCategory
))
-- Other case, @categoryID <> 0
OR (@categoryID <> 0 AND ItemCategoryID IN (
  SELECT CategoryID from SE_ItemCategory 
    WHERE ParentID=@categoryID OR CategoryID=@categoryID
))
```

Comment: Superb.. too quick.. Thanks a lot Michael.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't put an `if` in the middle of a SQL statement like that. There are a couple ways to accomplish this:

```
--Example 1
DECLARE @categoryID int = 0

SELECT * from SE_Auctions
WHERE 
ItemCategoryID IN
(SELECT CategoryID from SE_ItemCategory where @categoryID=0
union all
SELECT CategoryID from SE_ItemCategory 
    WHERE ParentID=@categoryID OR CategoryID=@categoryID) 

--Example 2
DECLARE @categoryID int = 0

SELECT * from SE_Auctions
WHERE 
(@categoryID=0
and ItemCategoryID IN
(SELECT CategoryID from SE_ItemCategory))
or (@categoryID <> 0
and ItemCategoryID IN
(SELECT CategoryID from SE_ItemCategory 
    WHERE ParentID=@categoryID OR CategoryID=@categoryID))

--Example 3
DECLARE @categoryID int = 0

SELECT * from SE_Auctions
WHERE 
ItemCategoryID IN
(SELECT CategoryID from SE_ItemCategory 
    WHERE ParentID=@categoryID OR CategoryID=@categoryID or @categoryID=0))
```